# Jquery loading all records on load

Tags: jquery, odata, loading, pageload

Current I have a scenario where I have to load records on scrollbar scrollevent.
I have a empty dropdown list and on first load I am appending first 20 records which are retrieved from server.
On dropdown scroll I am getting next 20 records from server and appending to dropdown.
I am repeating this process on scrollbar event and appending next 20 and next 20 records to dropdown.

Below is my code/algorithm.

My Question is : Do we have any option to load all records at a time instead of loading 20 from server?

Cons: My odata returns only 20 records at a time. Its page size is set to 20. I do not have control to odata update. I have to loop the scenario to get 20 by 20 each time and on page load it should sum all together.

```
var nextCitiesLink = null;
    var pgLoading = false;


    $("#SelectedNames").bind('scroll', function(e) {
      loadCityNames();
    });

    function loadCityNames() {
        if (!pgLoading && nextLinkPgs != null) {
            pgLoading = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: nextCitiesLink,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    var namesDrpdown = $('#SelectedNames');
                    $.each(result.value, function(val, data) {
                        namesDrpdown.append($('<option></option>').val(data.Id).html(data.Name));
                    });

                    nextCitiesLink= "odatalink&$skip=20";
                    pgLoading = false;
                },
                complete: function() {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make multiple requests to get the number of pages you need to populate your page.

A better idea would be to ask whoever can update the OData service to increase the page size. It would be a bad idea to allow clients request everything in one call.

Answer (score 0):

OData currently doesn't support overriding paging from the client side. No query option or preference header supports that.

However, if the OData service is built by you. You can configure the server to disable server-driven paging.

For the OData service built using ASP.NET Web API OData please refer to this to modify it:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging

For the service built using WCF Data Services Server you can refer to this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473424(v=vs.110).aspx